# Jquery - find links that have no target or a certain target

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to find all the links on a page that either have no target attribute or a target attribute that equals '***pageContent***' and for all matched elements I would like to apply an `onclick` event to them.

The `onclick` event is called `pgTrans('start')`. I'm not sure if it matters but some of the links may already have this event hard coded or attached via jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('a:not([target]), a[target="pageContent"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pgTrans('start');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UpjmU/

using [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and inside `[target]`, selects all `a` that don't have a `target` attribute. In the second case, using [[target="pageContent"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)], selects all elements that the attribute `target` equals `pageContent`

Answer (score 1):

The function will be called twice by any links that already have an event handler to do this attached.

```
$('a[target=""], a[target="pageContent"]').click(function(){
        pgTrans('start');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it did not work. Not sure why. The above worked however so I'm good to go.